Pyspark self join taking alot of time
I have pyspark df which I am self joining based on 2 columns
cluster_id which has different clusters with different counts and unique_id which is unique in every row.
df_filtered.repartition('cluster_id')

df_similar_cluster = df_filtered.alias('df1').join(
    df_filtered.alias('df2'),
    (F.col('df1.cluster_id') == F.col('df2.cluster_id')) &
    (F.col('df1.unique_id') < F.col('df2.unique_id')),
    'inner'
)

I tried repartition on cluster_id but it is still taking alot of time.
There are around 5k clusters each has different amount of records.
Total there are 4M records in the dataframe.

Your issue should be in the second join clause, which is the < comparison for the unique_id. This means that in each cluster, which should be ~800 rows, you are joining the first unique_id with all 799 others, the second with 798, and so on until 1. If you look at that sum of 1 to n here, you see that this should get close to n*(n+1)/2, which in your case should be around 320,000 rows per group.
Multiply this with your amount of clusters and you get that you should get around 1.6B rows in your resulting table.
This all is of course a rough estimation, but you can see what the effect of this join is and why the resulting dataset is much bigger than the original. If you are interested in having each combination of unique_id's per cluster_id present in your resulting dataset, then this might not be avoidable, but maybe you can look in your total process whether this is really what you need. So have a look at what you do afterwards, possibly filtering, and see whether things can be improved before this join.
